# Check for CWinApp existence

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have a process that was programed and used

```
CWinApp(
   LPCTSTR lpszAppName = NULL 
);
```

I know the lpszAppName.

By using the lpszAppName, I want to check whether this WinApp process exists or not.
How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: You should create a global mutex at program start, so you can check its existence at start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use named mutex:

At the beginning of program:

```
HANDLE hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE, "Your program name");
if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
{
    // Process already running.
    CloseHandle(hMutex);
}
else
{
    // No process running.
}
```

At the end of program:

```
if (hMutex)
{
    CloseHandle(hMutex);
    hMutex = NULL;
}
```